# Aggregate Math on TimeStamp fields

Tags: advantage-database-server

I need a timestamp difference calculated!. The purpose is to determine the number of records entered into a database expressed in records per hour. The sql is something like

```
SELECT (MAX(myTimeStampField)-MIN(myTimeStampField))/COUNT(*) FROM myTable
```

Which does not work :(

Answer (score 3):

This will give you records per hour:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / CONVERT( TIMESTAMPDIFF( SQL_TSI_HOUR, MIN( myTimeStampField ), 
                                          MAX( myTimeStampField )), SQL_DOUBLE ) 
      FROM myTable
```

You can read more about our SQL date & time functions [here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_date_time_functions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing the point, as it seems like a simple count(*) using between dt1 and dt2 would do the trick?

SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM tablex t
 WHERE t.dtfield BETWEEN dt1 AND dt2

Reinaldo.

Comment: You are correct that your suggestion would give me the total count of records created in the time span; but the return should be in "records per hour". Thanks for answering.